# Mann Kendall's and Seasonal Mann Kendall's Tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, seasonality

I have one year-long air pollutant concentration dataset of each 365 days of the year. I want to find if there is any seasonal trend in that data. Can you suggest to me if the Seasonal Kendall's test be applied to this data to find the seasonal trend?
In other words, can Seasonal Kendall's test be applied to one year-long daily data (n=365), when the period is only one?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My understanding of the seasonal Mann-Kendall test is that it looks at e.g., for monthly data, the same month across the years.  In your case, your time unit is a day, for one year, so there's no way it can compare e.g. January 1 to the other January 1's across years.  So, I don't think the test will be meaningful in your case. ...  You could use a different model which can include "season", however you define it.  Daily data will likely have auto-correlation, so you will likely want to include this effect, or at least investigate this effect, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Answer, from my comment:

My understanding of the seasonal Mann-Kendall test is that it looks at e.g., for monthly data, the same month across the years. In your case, your time unit is a day, for one year, so there's no way it can compare e.g. January 1 to the other January 1's across years. So, I don't think the test will be meaningful in your case.

You could use a different model which can include "season", however you define it.

Daily data will likely have auto-correlation, so you will likely want to at least investigate this effect as well.